# How to use 2 delimitters while reading from a file in PHP

Tags: php, file

I'm trying to create an online quiz web app and Im stuck with reading from the files that have the questions.enter code here. This is the file :

```
@$!#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
printf();
scanf();
}
@$!#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{  
printf();
scanf();
}
@$!#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
printf();
scanf();
}
```

SO i have to read from @$! to the next @$! while also the new line sequence should be maintained. MY php code looks like this

```
<?php
$filename = "newfile.txt";
$fd = fopen ($filename, "r");
$contents = fread ($fd,filesize ($filename));
fclose ($fd); 
$delimiter = "\n";
$splits= explode($delimiter, $contents);
foreach ( $splits as $show )
{

$ctr = explode("@$!",$show);
foreach($ctr as $nl)
echo $nl;

} 


 ?>
```

The output looks like this:

```
   #include void main() { printf(); scanf(); } #include void main() {   
   scanf(); } #include void main() { printf(); scanf(); }
```

all in one straight line. Anything Am i missing? Or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$filename = "update.txt";
$contents =  nl2br(file_get_contents($filename));
?>
```

Would you please use this to read file ?

**Result:**

```
@$!#include
void main()
{
printf();
scanf();
}
@$!#include
void main()
{
printf();
scanf();
}
@$!#include
void main()
{
printf();
scanf();
}
```

**Your modified code:**

```
<?php
$filename = "newfile.txt";
$contents =  nl2br(file_get_contents($filename));
$delimiter = "\n";
$splits= explode($delimiter, $contents);
foreach ( $splits as $show )
{

$ctr = explode("@$!",$show);
foreach($ctr as $nl)
echo $nl;

} 
?>
```

**Result:**

```
#include
void main()
{
printf();
scanf();
}
#include
void main()
{
printf();
scanf();
}
#include
void main()
{
printf();
scanf();
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.